# How can I unserialize a value from MySQL and assign the values in a variable using PHP/CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hello guys I just need a little help here about unserializing MySQL values. What I want is after getting the serialized value from my database I will assign the unserialized value in a variables.

Here's my code

```
//THIS IS THE QUERY

$sqlGetSerializedValues = "SELECT cscart_order_data.order_id AS order_id, cscart_order_data.data as data_serialize FROM cscart_orders
                           LEFT JOIN cscart_order_data
                           ON cscart_orders.order_id = cscart_order_data.order_id
                           WHERE type = 'I'";

$resultGetSerialize = $this->db->query($sqlGetSerializedValues);

$var_data = array();

foreach($resultGetSerialize->result_array() as $row1){
   $var_data[] = $row1['data_serialize'];
}
unserialize($var_data); //How can i get the selected value
print_r($var_data);

OUTPUT:

Array
(
    [0] => a:2:{s:6:"points";i:100;s:4:"cost";i:100;}
    [1] => a:2:{s:6:"points";i:100;s:4:"cost";i:100;}
    [2] => a:2:{s:6:"points";i:294;s:4:"cost";i:294;}
    [3] => a:2:{s:6:"points";d:107;s:4:"cost";d:107;}
    [4] => a:2:{s:6:"points";i:163;s:4:"cost";i:163;}
    [5] => a:2:{s:6:"points";i:322;s:4:"cost";i:322;}
    [6] => a:2:{s:6:"points";i:289;s:4:"cost";i:289;}
    [7] => a:2:{s:6:"points";i:9;s:4:"cost";i:9;}
    [8] => a:2:{s:6:"points";i:500;s:4:"cost";i:500;}
    [9] => a:2:{s:6:"points";i:500;s:4:"cost";i:500;}
    [10] => a:2:{s:6:"points";i:301;s:4:"cost";i:301;}
    [11] => a:2:{s:6:"points";i:500;s:4:"cost";i:500;}
    [12] => a:2:{s:6:"points";i:490;s:4:"cost";i:490;}
    [13] => a:2:{s:6:"points";i:103;s:4:"cost";i:103;}
```

For example I want to get the "points" and assign in a variable $points.
How can i do that? An also the cost. Ok that's all Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop you want to call that `unserialize` function in there:

```
foreach($resultGetSerialize->result_array() as $row1){
   $var_data[] = unserialize($row1['data_serialize']);
}
```

Then you'll wind up with a multidimensional array. Right now you're winding up with an array of serialized values.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to extract these values (which were [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)d by PHP, not MYSQL) is to use PHP's `unserialize()` function [(docs here)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)